# Navigation menu onclick scrolling issue?

Tags: html, css

When ever I click on header navigation menu It will scrolled to respective division but some part is hiding behind sticky header. How to fix this problem with css.

below is my fiddle link

```
      `https://jsfiddle.net/6t8d1Lne/1/
```

Comment: Please put the revelant part of your code directly in the question

Answer (score 1):

Add Extra padding equal to your header height to  all the sections and minus that extra padding in negative margin for example

```
.section-f {
        background: #75D5A7;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 350;
        padding: 150px /*assunming your header height is 100px so I add 100px in 50px padding*/;
        margin-top: -100px; /*extra padding removed*/
        font-family: Roboto;
    }
```

Comment: section-a, section-c, section-e working but section-f is not working. Background color is going to added to previous section i,e (section-e)